# Are there possibilities to change a mobile page smoothly and without jqm?

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am creating a Phonegap app and I really want to avoid jqm in the project, because the css is just blowing up the whole html code. So I can change the pages with

```
window.location = "profiles.html";
```

but that's a pretty hard cut in the user experience and I really want to change this to something more smooth. Are there any possibilities to enhance the changepage process, maybe with css or something?

Comment: you can try with [fullpage CSS animations](http://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-create-full-page-animations-using-css/)

Comment: You should choose a UI framework: ionic, onsenui, framework7,... Each frame work was build and handle many components, you can use immediate, only override several JS/CSS if you want. I used JQM for first, it rather slow, JS+CSS so much, difficult to override or change style.

Comment: These fullpage CSS animations are pretty cool, but I really want to give my users the look and feel of a native app, so I can't give them 500ms white screens while the new page is loading. Is it possible to preload the page, so that I could minimize the "white-screen" time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a fade effect.

```
var speed = 'slow';

$('html, body').hide();
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('html, body').fadeIn(speed, function() {
        $('a[href], button[href]').click(function(event) {
            var url = $(this).attr('href');
            if (url.indexOf('#') == 0 || url.indexOf('javascript:') == 0) return;
            event.preventDefault();
            $('html, body').fadeOut(speed, function() {
                window.location = "profiles.html";
            });
        });
    });
});
```

See it in [action (jsFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/akashacisne/hu9wW/)

Comment: I'm a bit confused, because this is still fading for me : [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hu9wW/129/) , but I think your code should work with .slideUp() or .animate() too shouldn't it?

Comment: Okay thanks, would it be possible to preload the pages, so that the new page is loading during the animation?